# Best way to write Html in a Webpart

Tags: web-part

What is the best way to write/output html in a webpart?

I am coming from PHP, there it was pretty straightforward.

I have seen the HtmlTextWriter, but I think that is very odd and makes it even more complicated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to output HTML directly using code then you should override the [RenderContents Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.rendercontents%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and call the methods on the [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt7b938d%28v=vs.90%29) it gets as parameter.

But many prefer to use ASP.NET controls which should be created inside an override of [CreateChildControls Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)